# How to fix this ( /home/user/MagnaFurn/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/ )?

Tags: angular

I have created the new project in angular in ubuntu 18.04 terminal but I am getting some error. I have tried all possible ways by installing in this way:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

and by updating ng and npm but there is no use the error is still the same

This is the error:

```
Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server
Error: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/home/user/MagnaFurn/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:49:19)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (/home/user/MagnaFurn/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:135:55)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "magna-furn",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you worked on. You can refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . The more details you provide, the more we can help you.

Comment: have you cnahged your node.js version?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Yeah I have changed the version too...

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I have not started writing the code. I have just created the new project but it is not getting compiled.

Comment: @RahelaMahenaz You had a project in which you added `@angular-devkit/build-angular`... Either share the minimal code through which we can replicate the issue or provide us the configurations so we can have a look to understand... currently we can only see that the project broke after adding the library.. but we have no idea what the project was and how did you created using which cli configurations..

Comment: @RahelaMahenaz updated the question with that.. :)

Comment: @HimanshuBansal Yeah I have updated the question.

Comment: @RahelaMahenaz I created a new project with the same packages.json and it ran.. not running into any issue. Maybe issue is related to some other application that you might be using or having in background...

Comment: @HimanshuBansal Ok Thank you...I tried all possible ways but no use.

Comment: @RahelaMahenaz I used the same ubuntu18.04 terminal on AWS and created a project and it worked. Most probably some issue with other applications that you have be running in background. Try creating a new project and see if he problem persist.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal unfortunately this suggestion also didn't work anyways thankyou  :)

Comment: @RahelaMahenaz have u tried in a new clean environment....??

Comment: @HimanshuBansal Finally...It got compiled I have just again installed the npm by creating new project and it worked.Thank god.....anyway thank you I kept trying thinking someone is replying to my problems(issues).

Comment: @RahelaMahenaz Nice its working ^^...

Answer (score 1):

Usually it happens because you have cnahged the node.js version ..but it still remain the npm cache (cable on precedent node.js version)

try to:

1- `UNINSTALL NODE.JS`

2 -  `Find the folder npm-cache and npm and DELETE IT`

3 - `REINSTALL NODE.JS` (globally)

4 - `GO IN PROJECT FOLDEER AND DELETE (rimraf ) NODE_MODULES`

5 - re run `npm i`

Hope it helps you!!